# Unit testing interceptor (axios)

Tags: unit-testing, http, mocha.js, sinon, axios

I use `axios` for the api calls in my `react` `redux` app. I added this interceptor to intercept the response for all the api calls and redirect user to login if the status code is 401.

```
axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  if (response.status === 401) {
    browserHistory.push('/login');
  }
  return response;
});
```

I am unit testing this and asserting on `browserHistory` spy to get called but I am not sure why my test keeps failing. I'm kind of stuck after loads of tries and am not able to sort out the issue. I am using `moxios` for mocking response.

**Test**

```
let sandbox;

  beforeEach(() => {
    moxios.install();
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    moxios.uninstall();
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  describe('interceptors', () => {
    it('should redirect to login if response status code is 401', (done) => {
      moxios.withMock(() => {
        sandbox.spy(browserHistory, 'push');

        axios.get('/test');

        moxios.wait(() => {
          const request = moxios.requests.mostRecent();
          request.respondWith({
            status: 401,
            response: {}
          }).then(() => {
            expect(browserHistory.push).to.have.been.called; // Fails
            done();
          }).catch(done);
        });
      });
    });
});
```

Any sort of resources or guide would be really appreciated. I am pretty sure I am missing something here.

Comment: I think you need to call `axios.get('/test')` after the `moxios.wait` definition.

Comment: Hey @anoop. I think I tried that as well but no luck. Any other suggestions?

Comment: updated as an answer, i think the response has to spy with a promise.

Comment: I wrote the [`axios-middleware` module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57498503/1218980) to ease testing and write self-contained HTTP middlewares, because I didn't like Axios' interceptors heavy coupling.