# Axios middleware to use in all instances of axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, middleware

I'm using axios in my react app using `import axios from 'axios` in many of my scripts. I want to use sort of a middleware that is invoked for all axios calls/errors. How do I approach this?

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As per the documentation - You need to create a file i.e

```
// api-client.js

import axios from 'axios';

// Add a request interceptor
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    console.log(config);
    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });

// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });

export default axios;
```

Then from your container or controller, import above file:

```
// Home.js
import apiClient from './api-client.js';
```

Answer (score 8):

Interceptors are the Axios way of doing this. For me though, it was too limited, tangled in Axios' API, difficult to test, etc.

## Axios-middleware

So I wrote the [*axios-middleware*](https://emileber.github.io/axios-middleware/#/) module, a simple middleware service that hooks itself in your axios instance (either global or a local one) and provides a simple, self-contained and easily testable middleware API.

***Note:** it shines in bigger apps where minimal coupling is really important.*

## Simple example

Here's a [simple example from the documentation](https://emileber.github.io/axios-middleware/#/?id=simplest-use-case)

> ```
> import axios from 'axios';
> import { Service } from 'axios-middleware';
>
> const service = new Service(axios);
>
> service.register({
>   onRequest(config) {
>     console.log('onRequest');
>     return config;
>   },
>   onSync(promise) {
>     console.log('onSync');
>     return promise;
>   },
>   onResponse(response) {
>     console.log('onResponse');
>     return response;
>   }
> });
>
> console.log('Ready to fetch.');
>
> // Just use axios like you would normally.
> axios('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
>   .then(({ data }) => console.log('Received:', data));
> ```
>
> It should output:
>
> ```
> Ready to fetch.
> onRequest
> onSync
> onResponse
> Received: {userId: 1, id: 1, title: ...
> ```

## [Testing a middleware](https://emileber.github.io/axios-middleware/#/examples/testing)

Say we have the following self-contained middleware class that we want to test.

```
export default class ApiErrorMiddleware {
  constructor(toast) {
    this.toast = toast;
  }

  onResponseError(err = {}) {
    let errorKey = 'errors.default';
    const { response } = err;

    if (response && response.status) {
      errorKey = `errors.${response.status}`;
    } else if (err.message === 'Network Error') {
      errorKey = 'errors.network-error';
    }

    this.toast.error(errorKey);
    throw err;
  }
}
```

Then it's really easy, we don't even need to mock Axios.

```
import ApiErrorMiddleware from '@/middlewares/ApiErrorMiddleware';

describe('ApiErrorMiddleware', () => {
  let toast;
  let middleware;

  // Jest needs a function when we're expecting an error to be thrown.
  function onResponseError(err) {
    return () => middleware.onResponseError(err);
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    toast = { error: jest.fn() };
    middleware = new ApiErrorMiddleware(toast);
  });

  it('sends a code error message', () => {
    expect(onResponseError({ response: { status: 404 } })).toThrow();
    expect(toast.error).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith('errors.404');
  });
});
```

Comment: https://github.com/crazyfactory/tinka a while ago we had middleware requirement and axois didn't support it, so we created tinka, now even though axios has it, the api is really crappy, so I still use tinka, it's much better IMO. specially to create SDKs for you API