# Use hooks in React Js axios interceptor while refresh token

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, redux-toolkit

In my React JS (Vite + TS) app
Used solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53256982/22404569
I am using it for refreshing tokens, BE sends `httpOnly` cookies as access_tokes so need for the FE to handle tokens.

**Problem**: I want to redirect user to /login when '/tokens-renew' API fails

**My approach**
I tried to do this using `handelLogout()`. **This approach cannot be done** because hooks can only be called inside of a functional component.

I believe `handelLogout()` is crucial as it manages all the flags that helps in keeping private route

**Please note** refreshing of tokens and retries of API is working perfectly fine, gets stuck in case of 401 for `/tokens-renew` and i want to redirect user.

```
export const handleLogout = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const showToast = useToast();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    // Clear the local storage and dispatch the signOut action to update the Login flag to false
    localStorage.clear();
    dispatch(signOut()); // Dispatch the action to sign out the user (e.g., clear authentication state in Redux)
    navigate("/login"); // Navigate to the login page 
    showToast("Session expired.", EToastTypes.WARNING); //A custom Hook for Toast msg
};
```

```
let isTokenRenewing = false;

...

axios.interceptors.response.use(
    res => res,
    async (err) => {
        // In case of token expire 
        if (err.response.status === 401 && !isTokenRenewing)//Cheks if any API has 401 and there was no req made prior to this 
        {
            isTokenRenewing = true;
            let url = import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASEURL + '/tokens-renew';
            try {
                const response = await axios.get(url);
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    return axios(err.config)
                }
            }
            catch (err) {
                // For case request /tokens-renew got 401 
                // handleLogout()
            }
        }
        // For case request was already made and got 401 
        else {
            // handleLogout()
        }

        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered handling that 401 outside the axios interceptor?

I'm thinking you could use a custom hook (https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks) where you call "/tokens-renew", and handle that response.

It'd look something like this:

```
export function useIsLoggedIn() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const showToast = useToast();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const apiResponse = service.callAPI(); // Here you'd call tokens-renew

  if(apiRespose.response.status === 401) {
    localStorage.clear();
    dispatch(signOut()); 
    navigate("/login"); 
    showToast("Session expired.", EToastTypes.WARNING);
  }
}
```

And then you can use that hook wherever you need it, you can alse wrap the API call with a useEffect hook if you want to call that API periodically.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. Thank you for posting.